# how to popup javafx application?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a javafx application which represents for the user the rates of currencies.
I want to be able to pop up the application when some trigger happen, even if the user has the application minimized.
For example: suppose the $ currency is hitting a target of 1$ = 0.86€, I want to alert the user, even if he has the application minimized on his screen, and bring it to the front.
Is that possible?

Comment: See [`Stage#iconified`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#iconifiedProperty) and [`Window#requestFocus()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html#requestFocus())/[`Stage#toFront()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#toFront()). What actually happens with the latter methods may be platform specific.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `setIconified`, `setX` and `setY` methods from `Stage` and put it into a thread. Check this:

```
while(alive){
   if(##YOUR STATEMENT##){
      Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
      primaryStage.setX((screenBounds.getMaxX() - primaryStage.getWidth()) / 2);
      primaryStage.setY((screenBounds.getMaxY() - primaryStage.getHeight()) / 2);
      primaryStage.setIconified(false);
      primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
   }

   try {
      Thread.sleep(CHECK_INTERVAL);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

This will show your window exactly at the center of the screen.

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but you can type `primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(false)` after `primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true)`. After your that window should be able to be covered by another windows.